# Running a Python code through bash command on windows

Tags: python, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to run a python code through a bash command on windows and it seems that my NumPy library is not seen at all. I already enabled WLS on windows and I have the Ubuntu distribution installed. I tried to run a sample NumPy code and it works normally. I will be appreciated any tips/help

[image]

Comment: Can you run `bash -c "python -V"` to see which python installation you are using ?

Comment: Hi, Philippe thank you for your comment. I managed to solve the issue by just writing bash only to move to the bash system then I was able to install the required package on it.

Comment: Please do not paste images of text but the text directly

Comment: @MMM Since you say you have solved your problem, please consider writing that as an answer (rather than a comment) and self-accept it.  That will allow the question to be "closed".  Otherwise the community-bot will bump it every so often looking for an answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**WSL uses hypervisor through a Vxhd, its literally a new virtual operating system with its own file system, so you need to install a build or programming env.**

bash uses `python3` and `pip3` terminal commands.

if you wish to bypass this function

first go into your wsl distro...

```
C:\Windows\System32> ubuntu
```

note : you can see the wsl distributions with the command `wsl -l` i would highly recommend running `wsl --set-version ubuntu 2` to set the WSL version to WSL2. Many Many improvements

now...
within WSL

```bash
sudo apt install python3 && sudo apt install pip3 && sudo apt install python-is-python3
pip install NumPy
```

might be helpful, if this doesnt work, let me know.